# Mariabackup creates huge incremental database backups

Tags: mariadb

I’ve been using these commands to create a full:

```
mariabackup --backup 
--target-dir=/home/ubuntu/mariaDB-backup/2019-10-07_13:57:03-full  
--user=NOTSHOWN --password=NOTSHOWN
```

And this to create a incremental backup:

```
mariabackup --backup  
--incremental-basedir=/home/ubuntu/mariaDB-backup/2019-10-07_13:57:03-full  
--target-dir=/home/ubuntu/mariaDB-backup/2019-10-07_14:02:10-incr  
--user=NOTSHOWN --password=NOTSHOWN
```

On my test database all went fine and the incremental is small,
but now on a bigger database the incremental is 11GB and the full is
12GB in size.

There are no connections beside the backup script to the server. What did go wrong here?

Comment: Odd. Have you tried running the same commands with `--compress`?

Comment: Alright, doing a full with compress did make it bigger (+4GB) but the incremental went down to 2GB. doing a incremental from the incremental also  resulted in a 2GB folder...since nothing changed, whats in the 2GB data? Now doing a incremental from a incremental without adding the --compress option (the first incremental was compressed) results in 11GB from 2Gb compressed. apparently theres data in there that can't be compressed?